# Applications won't run after reinstallation of 16.04 (64 bit)

Tags: unity, 16.04, vlc

I have just reinstalled 16.04 on a new machine after running it a few days. Oddly, most of the applications I have since downloaded from Ubuntu Software have not run properly. Evolution installs but does not run. VLC installs but does not run. Pan installs but does not run. GIMP installs but runs without any menus. A couple others are running OK. Icons of the ones that don't run just hang in the dock and usually won't even quit unless I restart or log out. They also don't run when I try opening them via the Terminal, though VLC said it was already running (no windows were visible) and Pan complained about a .system file. What would cause such a broad-based change? These apps were running fine on the same machine and the same operating system a day ago. I have run apt-get update and updated Unity.

Comment: please check logs for any trace of issue. are  you using unity or gnome?

Answer (score 0):

Work around found. The problem apparently was something with Unity. I switched to Ubuntu Mate and everything is fine.